# Returning a pair of items from a function

Tags: c, assembly

I know all the normal ways of doing this, what I'm looking for is an article I read a long long time ago that showed how to write some crazy helper functions using inline assembly and __naked functions to return a pair of items.

I've tried googling for it endlessly, but to no avail, I'm hoping someone else knows the article I'm talking about and has a link to it.

Comment: StackOverflow isn't, in general, a search service.  This is a very localized request -- that is -- you're asking for an article, not really help on programming, so I'm voting to close this as localized.

Comment: I suggest that the question just be edited so that it doesn't specifically ask for that article, but any information for dealing with the issue.  Providing the location of that article would answer that question, but so could many other answers.  I see no problem with the question mentioning that a long lost half remembered article may have dealt with this.

Comment: Yeah, this isn't an A/B problem. I know what I'm asking for, and searching hasn't turned up anything. If you can suggest somewhere better to ask, feel free.

Answer (score 11):

No assembly necessary

```
struct PairOfItems {int item1;double item2;};
struct PairOfItems crazyhelperfunction(void){
    struct PairOfItems x = {42, -0.42};
    return x;
}
```

I don't know about the article.

Comment: Nice implementation of the supplied specs.  :-)

Comment: I thought this was one of the normal ways of doing it!

Comment: LOL You caught me Juan. I *cheated*

Comment: I'm quite aware of how to return a struct, or an array, or just a pointer to some memory. I'm looking for that article.

Comment: Yup, using a struct is about as good as it'll get in C.  If you're using C++ you could use the "pair" type.  At least pmg didn't recommend using void*.  :D

Comment: It won't work as you expect due to return value optimization. The real prototype would be `crazyhelperfunction(PairOfItems*)`.

Answer (score -1):

The `__naked` that I know of is

```
#define __naked __attribute__((naked))
```

Which is a GCC attribute that is documented [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html).

It is not supported on all targets.  Doing a [google code search](http://www.google.com/codesearch?as_q=__naked&btnG=Search+Code&hl=en&as_package=&as_lang=&as_filename=&as_class=&as_function=&as_license=&as_case=) will turn up some uses of it, though.

The reasons that it is done as a macro is so that it can be defined as empty for targets that don't support it or if the headers are being used with some other compiler.

I do remember (I think) seeing some examples of this for the division and modulation (`divmod`) functions for avr_gcc headers.  This returned a struct that had both return values in it, but stored the whole thing in registers rather than on the stack.

I don't know if `__naked` had anything to do with the ability to return both parts of the result (which were in a struct) in registers (rather than on the stack), but it did allow the inline function to consist entirely of a call to one helper function.